# making UI take precedence

Tags: javascript

How can I create an environment in client-side javascript where any code related to user interface and views takes precedence over other code?

I know you can push things to next tick with `setTimeout([function],0);`

How could I build a system to do this on a widespread basis?

Comment: One possibility is to split your design elements into iframes and load them in order of priority, check out http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/11/02/how-to-load-iframes-in-order-according-to-priority/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded (except for webworkers in the latest browsers) so you only have two options:

1. Put non-UI related work into one or more webworkers so it can be done in the background.
2. Do ALL non-UI related work in small chunks where each chunk of work is done on the enxt `setTimeout()`.  This allows pending UI interactions to be done between each tick of non-UI work.  This is a lot of work to code, but can be made to work if it's really worth the effort.

Here's an example, I adapted from some other long-running code I had: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JJUgv/